# Can we call ajax get method without appending parameters to url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest

I know that when pass parameters in get method, it will be appended to url. Is there any way to pass the parameters in get method without appending to URL.
e.g

```js
function ajaxgetCall()
{
$.ajax({
  url: "http://test.com",
  type: "get", //send it through get method
  data: { 
    UserID: "test", 
    EmailAddress: "test@test.test"
  },
  success: function(response) {
    console.log("Sucess");
  },
  error: function(xhr) {
    console.log("Error");
  }
});
};
ajaxgetCall();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

So here url would be,

> http://test.com/?UserID=test&EmailAddress=test%40test.test

What I want :

> http://test.com/

Is it possible to pass the parameters as we pass in post method.

Comment: Any reason for not using the `POST` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to pass the parameters as we pass in post method.

If you mean in body then no, because GET method does not allow body. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET)

But you could use headers for  example `$.ajax({ headers: {UserID: "test"}})`
In that case you'd need to modify your server code to extract data from headers.

Answer (score 0):

This is the feature of GET method.

If you don't want to append the properties to URL, must be use POST method.